# Install program in Wine and analyze traffic

Tags: ubuntu, security

I need to install a Windows program in Wine and I would like to analyze how reliable it is, that is, if it does not generate any connection that can transfer my information without realizing it.

This program is a software of notes and although I have paid the license and I keep in contact with the developer (recently I have communicated a bug), I would like to make sure that it is totally reliable as far as it can be detected.

How can this be done?

My operating system is Ubuntu.

Comment: tcpdump to track every packet on your system but filter its port only? You can find its sockets using netstate

Answer (score 1):

Run **tcpdump** in the one console:

```
tpcdump -i interface_name -n -s 0 -w /tmp/capture.cap
```

Install the program in wine

Go back to the tcpdump terminal and interrupt it with CTRL + C; after that analyze the traffic dumped by the tool; you have two ways:

- With `tcpdump -r /tmp/capture.cap`
- With a more graphical or user friendly tool such as **wireshark**.